# How to link the page layout file to the master page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem joining the page layout file to the master page. But nothing seems to show from my master page.

Below is my page layout for 2 column:

[image]

Below is my master page where i place my page layout inside it:

[image]

This is how my file directory look like:

[image]

The word "HAHDSDJl....." should appear in my master page. But it does not show. and i have no idea why.

Comment: I think you need to understand the use of PageLayout and Masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand the use of PageLayout and Masterpage. MasterPages are used to unify the look for your website. while Page Layouts are used to provide a 2 - 3 columns to put web parts in it.

Master Pages can not have content from page layouts in any way.

So if you want to display a content from PageLayout in a master page then its not possible.

Let me know If I miss anything or wongly understand your question

Thanks